# PYTHON - Add on to list

Tags: python

What can I write that will add on whatever the user inputs (raw_input / input) to an already existing list? Also, this will have to continue on. For example, if the user adds one item to a list, it will ask if they would like to add another. And if the answer is yes, then it will add another item to the list.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Look at the `append` method of a list ... This is pretty basic stuff ... Have you tried breaking your problem into small steps and googling each?

Comment: @mgilson I have a hard time learning these things. I do remember append, but it just didn't come to mind. Thank you.

Comment: It'd be easier to say "Enter new list item (or just press enter to finish):" if empty values aren't valid input - then you've only got one input loop and condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mylist = []
while 1:
    mylist.append(raw_input(': '))
    if raw_input('Add another? (Y/n): ')[0].lower() == 'n':
        break
```

even shorter:

```
mylist = []
while 1:
    mylist.append(raw_input(': '))
    if mylist[-1] == '': break
```

Comment: Or `mylist = list(iter(lambda: raw_input(': '), ''))` to get code golfy :)

Comment: Heh, thought of doing a lambda but i guessed that it was way to overkill for the OP :) nice one tho, never thought of adding iter() to it, +1 for that!

Comment: Wouldn't you need `del mylist[-1]` after the second example to remove the last element?

Comment: @captainjamie Yes you would, i just came up with a short solution for the problem that wasn't to obscure. But you're right, it's not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Make an empty list. Then start an endless loop where you read the user input and append to the list. The break depends on another user input ("yes" or "no").